# Having trouble importing a function from date-fns in one component but not another?

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, date-fns

I am trying to import this function into one of my components from the `date-fns` library like so:

```
import { eachMonthOfInterval } from "date-fns";
```

and I am testing it like this within the component:

```
  let result = eachMonthOfInterval({
      start: props.state.startDate ? new Date(props.state.startDate) : '', 
      end: props.state.endDate ? new Date(props.state.endDate) : ''
    })

  console.log(result)
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting a `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

What is odd is I can use `format()` from `date-fns` in another component just fine when importing like this:

```
import {format} from "date-fns";
```

So... is this a bug or am I doing something glaringly wrong here?

EDIT: Here is a link to the docs https://date-fns.org/v2.14.0/docs/eachMonthOfInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this . 
first  , in your  terminal enter this(be sure terminal in project folder) :
`npm install date-fns --save`

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { eachMonthOfInterval } from 'date-fns'

class TimeInterval extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)

   }

   render() {
      var result = eachMonthOfInterval({
         start: new Date(2014, 1, 6),
         end: new Date(2014, 7, 10)
       })
       console.log(result);
      return (
         <div>
            <h1 id='title'>Interval</h1>
            <table id='students'>
               <tbody>

               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default TimeInterval;
```

[image]

Comment: Tried that earlier... I receive a module not found error, unfortunately.

Comment: can you try this  :                                                                                                           
    var result = eachMonthOfInterval({
      start: new Date(2014, 1, 6),
      end: new Date(2014, 7, 10)
    })

Comment: Already did; it's definitely not the date object or the formatting.  The function is not importing into the component, even though it is pulling from the correct location.  It is almost if there is a problem with my environment and that specific function... but I am not for sure.

Comment: I think there is something more to it... I tried using that function in the component that works and it still gave me a TypeError.  May be a library problem?

Comment: Yeah, it still will not work... it is definitely an issue with my environment and I have no idea what it is.  It is pretty frustrating to be honest.

Comment: Okay, just to test, I literally copied and pasted your whole component into my project.  I imported it into my parent container and still got a TypeError.  I have no clue what to do.

Comment: Can you upgrate your nodejs versiyon  ?  https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/

Comment: Bahtiyar, what version of date-fns does your package.json show?

Comment: date-fns version : 2.14.0.

Comment: I'm embarrassed lol.  It was a version issue... a majority of the interval types appear to have been added in later versions.  I was only at 1.30.0.  Thanks for all your help; I'll give you the answer since you stuck with me for so long.